# Is there any difference between using WeightedRandomSampler with a big num_samples or doing more epoch with a num_samples lower?

Tags: pytorch, sampling, resampling, subsampling, statistical-sampling

I don't understand when the sampling is make:

Does the first mini batch will be the same for each epoch?
Or there no difference at all?